# echo combinations with special character as elements

Tags: bash, shell, brace-expansion

I've a small script which takes advantage of the echo ability to generate combinations of elements. That's the piece of code,

```
set={1,2,3,4}
group=3
for ((i=0; i<$group; i++));
do
  repetition=$set$repetition
done

bash -c "echo "$repetition""
```

That works fine, the problem comes when I want the set to consist of some special characters, like commas, parenthesys, etc. I've tried with scapes but it doesn't seem to work, something like

```
set={(,),\,,=}
```

Any clue about how to achieve it?

Comment: Quote and escape: `echo {"(",")","\\","="}{1,2}` works.

Comment: Thank you fedorqui, that seems to be in the way to the solution, but it fails in the last sentece of the script: "syntax error near unexpected token `(' " I guess it needs some kind of double scape ...

Comment: Yes, I was checking the full script and it also failed to me. I guess the solution is to add another "layer" of escaping sequences, because it has to go through `bash -c`.

Comment: For example this works: `set={1,2,3,"\'4\'"}`.

Comment: Yes, that works fine, even with parenthesis, the solution is double scape: one with " and the inner with \. Thank you fedorqui. If you write the answer, I'll give you the solution check ;)

Comment: `bash -c "echo "$repetition"" | tr '1234' '()\='` would be one way - do the combinations with normal characters and then replace them all in the output...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to quote and escape:

```
set={1,2,3,"\'4\'"}
```

Note that it was working with `{1,2,3,4}` because it is digits. For strings you also need to quote: `{1,2,3,'a'}`

```
$ echo {1,2,3,'a'}{1,2,3,'a'}
11 12 13 1a 21 22 23 2a 31 32 33 3a a1 a2 a3 aa
```

And then the escaping is to handle the execution of `bash -c` together with the values.

---

From your comments, your final script is:

```
set={"\(","\)","\,"}
group=3
for ((i=0; i<$group; i++));
do
  repetition=$set$repetition
done

bash -c "echo "$repetition""
```

When I execute it I get this, nice!

```
$ ./a
((( (() ((, ()( ()) (), (,( (,) (,, )(( )() )(, ))( ))) )), ),( ),) ),, ,(( ,() ,(, ,)( ,)) ,), ,,( ,,) ,,,
```

Comment: Yes, it works fine, and for the special characters it would be something like set={"\\(","\\)","\,"}. Thank you fedorqui.

Comment: +1 but where are the `.` coming from? Did you just add them for clarity?

Comment: @terdon ops! I had set the `set` variable to `set={"\(","\)","\,"}.` with a trailing dot, hence the output. I didn't notice, thanks for letting me know :)

Answer (score 2):

While @fedorqui's answer is the way to go, here's a bit more information for completeness. You know that special characters need to be escaped, but `\` is, itself a special character so *that* needs to be escaped as well since you are passing it to another bash instance.

So, when you have `set={(,)}` in your script, your script will throw a syntax error because of the parentheses. Once you escape them as `set={\(,\)}` your script is OK with them *but* has already expanded them by the time you pass them to your `bash -c` which instead will see `set={( )}` and choke on that, giving the same syntax error:

```
$ set={\(,\)}; echo Parent: "$set";  bash -c "echo Child1: "$set""
Parent: {(,)}
bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: -c: line 0: `echo Child1: {(,)}'
```

The obvious solution would be to escape the backslashes themselves, so they will be passed correctly. However, escaping causes a character to loose its special powers, so escaping the `\` will stop it from escaping the parentheses:

```
$ set={\\(,\\)};
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

So, back to square one. What you have to do is escape the escape that is escaping the escape<sup>1</sup>:

```
$ set={\\\(,\\\)}
$ echo "Parent3: $set"
Parent3: {\(,\)}
$ bash -c "echo Child3 "$set""
Child3 ( )
```

Here, the child instance is finally being passed what it needs to see: `{\(,\)}`. So, while it is not strictly necessary to use quotes in such cases, they really make your life much, much easier:

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Try saying *that* 5 times quickly.</sub>

Comment: Fantastic explanation. I came to something similar but then was surprised by `set={"\(","\)","\,"}` working, so I just stopped. Well done!

Comment: Thanks Terdon! Your answer helps a lot to understand how things work.